# RequireJs optimizer ignore plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, js-amd

I would like to ignore the use of a require js plugin when I use the optimizer

`define(["css!styles.css"])`

This always gives me this error
`Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined`.

I've set this options to the require optimizer

`{
   paths : {
   'css' : 'empty:'
   }
}`

But it keeps giving me the error.

Comment: Any updateds on this? Did you finde the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you want, but you could stub out the css plugin.

```
//Specify modules to stub out in the optimized file. The optimizer will
//use the source version of these modules for dependency tracing and for
//plugin use, but when writing the text into an optimized bundle, these
//modules will get the following text instead:
//If the module is used as a plugin:
//    define({load: function(id){throw new Error("Dynamic load not allowed: " + id);}});
//If just a plain module:
//    define({});
//This is useful particularly for plugins that inline all their resources
//and use the default module resolution behavior (do *not* implement the
//normalize() method). In those cases, an AMD loader just needs to know
//that the module has a definition. These small stubs can be used instead of
//including the full source for a plugin.
stubModules: ['text', 'bar'],
```

So in your case:

```
stubModules: ['css']
```

More details, see [Requirejs Optimizer Config options](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)