# RequireJS optimization fails when referencing a plugin (xstyle/css)

Tags: dojo, requirejs-optimizer

I followed the example file structure as described in http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html and got a working build.  I then modified two.js to look like this:

```
define(["xstyle/css!app/css/main.css"], function () {
    console.log("two");
});
```

And added xstyle/css to build.js:

```
({
    baseUrl: "./scripts",
    paths: {
        dojo: "empty:",
        xstyle: "empty:"
    },
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

Add ran the build again:

> r.js.cmd -o build.js optimize=none

And now I'm seeing this error:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined
In module tree:
    main
      two

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined
In module tree:
    main
      two

    at Object.<anonymous> (bin\r.js:1187:35)
```

There are numerous references to this same error but none resolve this specific issue (e.g.):

[Requirejs can't compile my dojo-dependent module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481440/requirejs-cant-compile-my-dojo-dependent-module)

[RequireJs optimizer ignore plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194147/requirejs-optimizer-ignore-plugin)

https://github.com/odoe/AGSModularDemo

Is it possible to optimize a dojo application using requirejs?

Comment: No answers? Did you find the solution?

Comment: @MarioMurrent - typescript + dojo2 make this unecessary since tsc can output AMD to a single file (in theory) but no, I didn't use r.js.  Dojo and my product source are in two separate files.

Comment: Alright, thank you